# Are there any browser-based multi-player capable libraries for C++?

Tags: c++, silverlight, flash

I've made a bunch of games from my own homegrown C++/DirectX 2D engine. I was thinking some of them would be more fun with the introduction of multi-player and at the very least it would be easier to distribute them and get people to play if they could run in a browser.

I'm looking to port my games into a web format and I don't think there is anything I'm doing that Flash or Silverlight can't handle. However I don't know either of those so while I could learn something new it would save time and make porting easier if I could find something in C++. Does anyone know of a preferably open source, or otherwise freely available, library I could use to give myself a leg up?

I've heard of [Haxe](http://haxe.org/) and it seems to be similar to what I want although it introduces a new language that can be converted to C++, ActionScript, etc. I'd prefer C++ so I can reuse some code without much of a fuss.

I also found something called [RakNet](http://www.jenkinssoftware.com/index.html) which may only be useful as a networking layer to my existing C++/DirectX games but less useful for a browser based games. Has anyone used this with success? How was it to implement and integrate with existing projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no.  C++ requires the code to be compiled into a binary executable, and for various reasons, such code is not allowed to be run in the browser.

The long answer: The [native client](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/) by Chromium/Google allows you to write native C++ code and run it in the browser.  However, support is *very* limited, in the sense that almost no browser allows it (beyond some experimental nightly builds of Chromium and such), and you're likely going to face the same issues when porting C++ code to a different OS (aka, just because it's in the browser doesn't mean it's going to run on that obscure Linux OS).

If you want to port your games to the web, you options are either re-write it for the web, or wait a few years/decades for the native client to become widespread.

Funfact: Most mobile devices allow for C++ code to be run with a minimal wrapper.  It's not the web, but it's an option if your goal is to get more people playing your games.

Comment: Thanks, that's kind of what I was expecting. If I were to re-write which technology would you recommend? Flash, Silverlight, HTML5, etc. Mind you this would only be for the client web application I think most of the work will be server side.

Comment: That's almost a full question by itself, and depends a bit on the game.  Flash/Silverlight are great for fast paced action games, HTML5 makes it pretty easy to communicate with a server.  Flash is very popular for game portals, Silverlight less so, HTML5 is just beginning to be noticed.  Personally, I'd start with Flash/AS3, as it's the most 'viable' option right now.